# SSIS Extract data from one version of sql to another

Tags: ssis

Can I extract data from databases on Sql server 2008 R2 using SSIS package on Sql 2014. I have developed the package using Visual studio 2015

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can.  Just use the correct Provider for SQL Server 2008 R2 in the connection.